# Moving by page without chords in Vim

Tags: editors, cursor, vim

Often I want to skim through a document or piece of code, which I do with page down (Ctrl-D) and page up (Ctrl-U), but it feels like I am violating the spirit of Vim using emacs-like chords/control keys. Is there a non-control key method of skimming through a document?

Comment: `}` and `{` skips through paragraphs...

Comment: You are not "violating the spirit" of `vim`, those are the keys defined by `vim` for moving page by page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl-D, Ctrl-U, Ctrl-F, Ctrl-B are pretty standard for this, but there are a few other ways I've found useful:

Ctrl-E and Ctrl-Y scroll one line down and one line up, respectively, without moving the cursor (unless it would be moved off the screen, of course).  These are handy because they accept counts, i.e., 5Ctrl-E will "Expose" five more lines at the bottom of the screen.

zz (lowercase!) scrolls the text to place the line the cursor is on in the center of your screen (or window in gvim)

zt scrolls to place the current line at the top of your screen

zb scrolls to place the current line at the bottom of your screen

And H, M and L place the cursor respectively on the top, middle and bottom lines currently on the screen.

This means that Lzt scrolls down one page (minus one line) and Hzb scrolls up one page (minus one line), while Lzz and Hzz mirror pretty closely the behavior of Ctrl-D and Ctrl-U.

Although honestly, I usually just use Ctrl-D and Ctrl-U.  :)

Comment: More recently I discovered that `z<Enter>`, `z.` and `z-` have the same functionality as `zt`, `zz` and `zb`, but they're easier to type—you use both hands one key each, instead of left hand two keys.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have a normal keyboard:

- An equivalent of "page down (Ctrl-D)" which works with `vim` is <kbd>PgDn</kbd>.
- An equivalent of "page up (Ctrl-U)" which works with `vim` is <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

As for "violating the spirit of Vim using emacs-like chords/control keys", this presumes that emacs has some kind of patent on use of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and/or that vim is intended as a museum artifact demonstrating the limitations of relatively ancient and obscure hardware terminals.

Comment: That's even worse than using chord because then I am taking my entire hand off the standard key set.

Comment: As per your question the context here is "skim[ing] through a document or piece of code", so it is very very very very hard to take this seriously.  You are skimming through a document, but at the same time want to maintain position for all the touch typing you are doing?  Perhaps your palms have been welded to the deck?!? **Obviously this was a drastic oversight in potential use-cases.**